# PHP background script can't access temporary file from upload

Tags: php, shell, background, upload

I have a PHP script which receives an upload and defers processing of that upload to a background script via `shell_exec()`.

But the background script can't seem to access the temporary file of the upload.

Receiver script

```
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo $file_loc.' exists = '.file_exists($file_loc);
shell_exec('php background.php -i='.$file_loc.' >report.txt &');
```

This outputs

> {path to file} exists = 1

Background.php

```
$args = getopt('i:');
$file_loc = $args['i'];
echo $file_loc.' exists = '.file_exists($file_loc);
```

In result.txt I get

> {path to file} exists =

i.e. doesn't exist. **What do I need to do to allow the background script to access the tmp file location?**

Comment: If the `$args['i']` is indeed correct, then it sounds like an issue related to `clearstatcache`

Comment: Hi, apparently the `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is deleted before the command is executed.

Comment: Try to look up the file manually. Can you find it using the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the uploaded file to a new destination to process the file.

```
$destination = "FOLDER_NAME/".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file ( $file_loc, $destination )
echo $destination.' exists = '.file_exists($destination);
shell_exec('php background.php -i='.$destination.' >report.txt &');
```

Comment: Thanks. I did consider this but I wanted to first check if this was the only option.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite your question then? 